# 日本語に違和感:「特権」と「権限」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

「ヘルプ センター > 権限」を見ると以下のような説明になっている。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

「特権」と「権限」という言葉が使われているが、英語サイトを見るとどちらも「Privileges」になっているので、どちらかに統一したほうが良い。私は「特権」を「権限」に修正した方が良いと思う。

Comment: 「特権」が多くなところに使っているため、[専門用語](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/)に追加し、後日全サイトに適用します。